# Rails/Uberspacify: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, uberspace, uberspacify

I am testing [uberspace.de](http://uberspace.de) with *[uberspacify](https://github.com/yeah/uberspacify)*, a *[capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano)* receipes collection. Before I started with *uberspacify* I configured the server as described in the [documentation provided by uberspace](https://uberspace.de/dokuwiki/cool%3arails). My RubyOnRails app just launched nicely. Now that I deployed via *uberspacify*, the following error is written in `/var/www/virtual/john/logs/error_log`:

> [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy:
>   HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:44477 (*) failed

Note that the port 44477 is a different each time I deploy.
The website itself states:

```
503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to 
maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at foobar.phoenix.uberspace.de Port 443
```

Here is the `Capfile` I prepared:

```
# Capfile
load 'deploy'
# Uncomment if you are using Rails' asset pipeline
load 'deploy/assets'
load 'config/deploy' # remove this line to skip loading any of the default tasks
```

Here is the configuration in `deploy.rb`:

```
# config/deploy.rb

# include uberspacify base recipes
require "uberspacify/base"

# comment this if you don"t use MySQL
require "uberspacify/mysql"

# the Uberspace server you are on
server "phoenix.uberspace.de", :web, :app, :db, :primary => true

# your Uberspace username
set :user, "john"

# a name for your app, [a-z0-9] should be safe, will be used for your gemset,
# databases, directories, etc.
set :application, "foobar"

# the repo where your code is hosted
set :scm, :git
set :repository, "git@bitbucket.org:obama/#{application}.git"
set :branch, "master"

# optional stuff from here

# By default, your app will be available in the root of your Uberspace. If you
# have your own domain set up, you can configure it here
# set :domain, "www.dummyapp.com"

# By default, uberspacify will generate a random port number for Passenger to
# listen on. This is fine, since only Apache will use it. Your app will always
# be available on port 80 and 443 from the outside. However, if you"d like to
# set this yourself, go ahead.
# set :passenger_port, 55555

# By default, Ruby Enterprise Edition 1.8.7 is used for Uberspace. If you
# prefer Ruby 1.9 or any other version, please refer to the RVM documentation
# at https://rvm.io/integration/capistrano/ and set this variable.
set :rvm_ruby_string, "1.9.3@#{application}"
```

I ran the following commands:

```
$ bundle exec cap deploy:setup
$ bundle exec cap deploy:migrations
```

I wonder if *uberspacify* takes care of all the configuration. The [uberspace tutorial for RubyOnRails](https://uberspace.de/dokuwiki/cool%3arails) works with *fcgi* and an `.htaccess` with rewrite rules. Also they do **not** use *rvm*.

Here is the `Gemfile` of the application:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.13'
gem 'counter_culture', git: 'https://github.com/dorilla/counter_culture'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.0.2'
gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.11.4', require: 'v8'
gem 'attribute_normalizer', '~> 1.1.0'
gem 'pry', '~> 0.9.12.2'

# Parsing ShapeFiles
gem 'rgeo', '~> 0.3.20'
gem 'rgeo-shapefile', '~> 0.2.3'
gem 'georuby', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'dbf', '~> 2.0.6'
gem 'gdal', '~> 0.0.5'

gem 'capistrano', '~> 2.15.5'
gem 'uberspacify', '~> 0.9.3'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.13'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '~> 2.1.1'
end

group :development do
  gem 'debugger', '~> 1.6.0'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.7'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.14.0'
  gem 'rspec-smart-formatter', '~> 0.0.4', require: false
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
  gem 'factory_girl_extensions', '2.1.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.13'
end
```

Of interest might be that I needed to install the *gdal* library via the *toast* package manager, via: `$ toast arm gdal` before I could successfully install `$ gem install gdal`. This gem is needed for parsing ShapeFiles.

---

I noticed that there is no `~/.passenger` directory after `deploy:setup` and `deploy:migrations` successfully processsed.

Comment: You might want to change the subject of your question to include uberspacify and rails since your problem is specific to those two rather than uberspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved with the great help of @patheticpat !!!

Here are the steps that were helpful to analyse the problem on the server.

- To check if the webserver was running at all run `$ curl http://localhost:{PORT}`. The port can be found in `~/html/.htaccess` or in `~/service/rails-{yourapp}/run`.
- To manually start the server execute `$ ~/service/rails-{yourapp}/run` and watch out for errors.
- The current deployment can be found in `/var/www/virtual/$USER/rails/{yourapp}/current`.
- To start Passenger manually run `$ bundle exec passenger start -p $PORT -e production`
- To start Passenger as a service run `$ svc -u ~/service/rails-{yourapp}`
- To stop Passenger service run `$ svc -d ~/service/rails-{yourapp}`

In this process of trial and error we found out that there is `PATH` problem and we noticed that `~/service/rails-{yourapp}/run` sources `$HOME/.bash_profile` as can be seen [here](https://github.com/yeah/uberspacify/blob/34a07b3790ef5fd0c5849e73cc1ebce5052fcef7/lib/uberspacify/base.rb#L57). To mention is that I use *zsh* in combination with *oh-my-zsh* and **custom dotfiles**. We noticed that I already have configured *rvm* in `~/.zshrc`. This file already [contains a source command](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/dotfiles/blob/dd196e0a3129c5994adf42fa6dd4962c5c524bfb/zshrc#L64):

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

We found out that this actually hinders *rvm* to put the same statement into `~/.bash_profile` as it is already [documented here](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1850).

To summarize: If you remove the *rvm* configuration from your custom dotfiles uberspacify will perfectly setup and launch the webserver.

---

@uberspacify: I suggest you rewrite the *rvm* script to watch out for the warning mentioned [here](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1850) and react appropriate.

Comment: Uberspacify is open source. If you feel it should be changed, you are free to fork it and submit a pull request ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of Uberspacify. It seems that Passenger with your Rails app hasn't started (yet). This is why Apache reports "Connection refused" on port 44477 -- which is the port that uberspacify chose randomly for internal communication between Passenger and Apache.

To debug this, you might want to check out the log files in `/var/www/virtual/< your username>/rails/<your app>/shared/log`.

Also, please be sure to "undo" any configuration changes you did according to the instructions by Uberspace. Their instructions are intended for an FCGI-only deployment and have nothing to do (and are most likely incompatible) with Uberspacify. The only preconditions for using Uberspacify are a regular Rails app and an Uberspace account.

Comment: What is the **actual address** at which my project is reachable after deploying via *uberspacify*? Does it include [rewrite rules similar to what *uberspace* documents](https://uberspace.de/dokuwiki/cool%3arails)?

Comment: According to @patheticpat the project can be reached at `http://{user}.{host}.uberspace.de/` which would be `http://john.phoenix.uberspace.de/` in my example.

Comment: I reverted every configuration step I did with regards to the *Uberspace* instructions. I also reverted former deployments via *uberspacify* to start clean. Nonetheless, the same error occurs. The `production.log` in `.../shared/log` contains information about the asset compilation and the migration. Nothing more.